# How to use cache decorator with a recursive function in go?

Tags: go, closures, decorator, fibonacci

I want results of every `fib` execution to be stored in cache variable, but make `cached` decorator and `fib` function independent.

The thing is, decorated `fib` is executing not decorated `fib` inside itself.
I understand that decorated `fib` inside `main` is a local variable, but I can't redefine `fib` in global scope(or I don't know how)

Is this even possible?

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func cached(f func(int) int) func(int) int {
    cache := make(map[int]int)
    return func(x int) int {
        if _, ok := cache[x]; !ok {
            cache[x] = f(x)
            fmt.Println(len(cache))
        }
        value, _ := cache[x]
        return value
    }
}

func fib(x int) int {
    if x < 0 {
        return -1
    }
    if x == 0 || x == 1 {
        return 1
    }
    return fib(x-1) + fib(x-2)
}

func main() {
    fib := cached(fib)
    fmt.Println(fib(40))
    fmt.Println(fib(41))
    fmt.Println(fib(42))
    fmt.Println(fib(43))
}
```

This code output:

```
1
165580141
2
267914296
3
433494437
4
701408733
```

But 1, 2, 3 and 4 here should be 38, 39, 40, 41

Comment: *The thing is, decorated fib is executing not decorated fib inside itself.* Can you clarify that bit? I don't understand what the issue is...

Comment: @jub0bs for example, in python if you define function ```foo``` that executes itself and you decorate it - ```foo``` will execute decorated version of itself, not the initial one. Is it possible to implement something like this in Go?

Comment: No, there is not.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the internal fib instead of the cached fib is being called. You can make the following change:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func cached(f func(int) int) func(int) int {
    cache := make(map[int]int)
    return func(x int) int {
        if _, ok := cache[x]; !ok {
            cache[x] = f(x)
        }
        value, _ := cache[x]
        return value
    }
}

var (
    fib func(int) int
    fibCached func(int) int
)
func main() {
    fib = func(x int) int {
        fmt.Printf("call arg:%d\n", x)
        if x <= 1 {
            return x
        } else {
            return fibCached(x-1) + fibCached(x-2)
        }
    }
    fibCached = cached(fib)
    fmt.Println(fibCached(40))
    fmt.Println(fibCached(41))
    fmt.Println(fibCached(42))
    fmt.Println(fibCached(43))
}
```

Alternatively, you can use this [gofnext decorator package](https://github.com/ahuigo/gofnext) to implement it.

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "github.com/ahuigo/gofnext"
func main() {
    var fib func(int) int
    fib = func(x int) int {
        fmt.Printf("call arg:%d\n", x)
        if x <= 1 {
            return x
        } else {
            return fib(x-1) + fib(x-2)
        }
    }

    fib = gofnext.CacheFn1(fib, nil)    

    fmt.Println(fib(5))
    fmt.Println(fib(6))
}
```